NextJS Drizzle-Kit cannot use CLI
I am using the drizzle auth template and trying to modify it to add Role Based Authentication. So I made some changes to the db.ts to add in the roles
import { drizzle } from 'drizzle-orm/postgres-js';
import { pgTable, serial, varchar } from 'drizzle-orm/pg-core';
import { eq } from 'drizzle-orm';
import postgres from 'postgres';
import { genSaltSync, hashSync } from 'bcrypt-ts';

// Optionally, if not using email/pass login, you can
// use the Drizzle adapter for Auth.js / NextAuth
// https://authjs.dev/reference/adapter/drizzle
let client = postgres(`${process.env.POSTGRES_URL!}?sslmode=require`);
let db = drizzle(client);

export async function getUser(email: string) {
  const users = await ensureTableExists();
  return await db.select().from(users).where(eq(users.email, email));
}

export async function createUser(email: string, password: string, role: string = 'learner') {
  const users = await ensureTableExists();
  let salt = genSaltSync(10);
  let hash = hashSync(password, salt);

  return await db.insert(users).values({ email, password: hash, role });
}

async function ensureTableExists() {
  const result = await client`
    SELECT EXISTS (
      SELECT FROM information_schema.tables 
      WHERE table_schema = 'public' 
      AND table_name = 'User'
    );`;

  if (!result[0].exists) {
    await client`
      CREATE TABLE "User" (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        email VARCHAR(64) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
        password VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
        role VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT 'user' NOT NULL
      );`;
  }

  const table = pgTable('User', {
    id: serial('id').primaryKey(),
    email: varchar('email', { length: 64 }),
    password: varchar('password', { length: 128 }),
    role: varchar('role', { length: 20 }),
  });

  return table;
}


However when I try to now update the database for this new column drizzle does not work as I cannot get the CLI to migrate or open the studio.
(base) PS C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\TemplatingDocuments\> npx drizzle-kit migrate
>> npx drizzle-kit push
No config path provided, using default 'drizzle.config.ts'
Reading config file 'C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\TemplatingDocuments\app\drizzle.config.ts'
Using 'pg' driver for database querying
[⣷] applying migrations...Error: Can't find meta/_journal.json file
    at readMigrationFiles (C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\TemplatingDocuments\node_modules\src\migrator.ts:29:9)
    at migrate (C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\TemplatingDocuments\node_modules\src\node-postgres\migrator.ts:9:21)
    at migrateFn (C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\TemplatingDocuments\node_modules\drizzle-kit\bin.cjs:61949:18)
    at Object.handler (C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\TemplatingDocuments\node_modules\drizzle-kit\bin.cjs:84856:11)
    at async run (C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\TemplatingDocuments\node_modules\drizzle-kit\bin.cjs:83343:7)No config path provided, using default 'drizzle.config.ts'
Reading config file 'C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\TemplatingDocuments\drizzle.config.ts'
Using 'pg' driver for database querying
[✓] Pulling schema from database...
C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\TemplatingDocuments\node_modules\bcrypt-ts\dist\node.mjs:1
import{randomBytes as R}from"node:crypto";const I=16,$=10,B=16,v=100,w="./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789".split(""),b=Array.from({length:64},(n,r)=>r),d=n=>Array(n).fill(-1),f=[...d(46),0,1,...b.slice(54,64),...d(7),...b.slice(2,28),...d(6),...b.slice(28,54),...d(5)],_=[608135816,2242054355,320440878,57701188,2752067618,698298832,137296536,3964562569,1160258022,953160567,3193202383,887688300,3232508343,3380367581,1065670069,3041331479,2450970073,2306472731],P=[3509652390,2564797868,805139163,3491422135,3101798381,1780907670,3128725573,4046225305,614570311,3012652279,134345442,2240740374,1667834072,1901547113,2757295779,4103290238,227898511,1921955416,1904987480,2182433518,2069144605,3260701109,2620446009,720527379,3318853667,677414384,3393288472,3101374703,2390351024,1614419982,1822297739,2954791486,3608508353,3174124327,2024746970,1432378464,3864339955,2857741204,1464375394,1676153920,1439316330,715854006,3033291828,289532110,2706671279,2087905683,3018724369,1668267050,732546397,1947742710,3462151702,2609353502,2950085171,1814351708,2050118529,680887927,999245976,1800124847,3300911131,1713906067,1641548236,4213287313,1216130144,1575780402,4018429277,3917837745,3693486850,3949271944,596196993,3549867205,258830323,2213823033,772490370,2760122372,1774776394,2652871518,566650946,4142492826,1728879713,2882767088,1783734482,3629395816,2517608232,2874225571,1861159788,326777828,3124490320,2130389656,2716951837,967770486,1724537150,2185432712,2364442137,1164943284,2105845187,998989502,3765401048,2244026483,1075463327,1455516326,1322494562,910128902,469688178,1117454909,936433444,3490320968,3675253459,1240580251,122909385,2157517691,634681816,4142456567,3825094682,3061402683,2540495037,79693498,3249098678,1084186820,1583128258,426386531,1761308591,1047286709,322548459,995290223,1845252383,2603652396,3431023940,2942221577,3202600964,3727903485,1712269319,422464435,3234572375,1170764815,3523960633,3117677531,1434042557,442511882,3600875718,1076654713,1738483198,4213154764,2393238008,3677496056,1014306527,4251020053,793779912,2902807211,842905082,4246964064,1395751752,1040244610,2656851899,3396308128,445077038,3742853595,3577915638,679411651,2892444358,2354009459,1767581616,3150600392,3791627101,3102740896,284835224,4246832056,1258075500,768725851,2589189241,3069724005,3532540348,1274779536,3789419226,2764799539,1660621633,3471099624,4011903706,913787905,3497959166,737222580,2514213453,2928710040,3937242737,1804850592,3499020752,2949064160,2386320175,2390070455,2415321851,4061277028,2290661394,2416832540,1336762016,1754252060,3520065937,3014181293,791618072,3188594551,3933548030,2332172193,3852520463,3043980520,413987798,3465142937,3030929376,4245938359,2093235073,3534596313,375366246,2157278981,2479649556,555357303,3870105701,2008414854,3344188149,4221384143,3956125452,2067696032,3594591187,2921233993,2428461,544322398,577241275,1471733935,610547355,4027169054,1432588573,1507829418,2025931657,3646575487,545086370,48609733,2200306550,1653985193,298326376,1316178497,3007786442,2064951626,458293330,2589141269,3591329599,3164325604,727753846,2179363840,146436021,1461446943,4069977195,705550613,3059967265,3887724982,4281599278,3313849956,1404054877,2845806497,146425753,1854211946,1266315497,3048417604,3681880366,3289982499,290971e4,1235738493,2632868024,2414719590,3970600049,1771706367,1449415276,3266420449,422970021,1963543593,2690192192,3826793022,1062508698,1531092325,1804592342,2583117782,2714934279,4024971509,1294809318,4028980673,1289560198,2221992742,1669523910,35572830,157838143,1052438473,1016535060,1802137761,1753167236,1386275462,3080475397,2857371447,1040679964,2145300060,2390574316,1461121720,2956646967,4031777805,4028374788,33600511,2920084762,1018524850,629373528,3691585981,3515945977,2091462646,2486323059,586499841,988145025,935516892,3367335476,2599673255,2839830854,265290510,3972581182,2759138881,3795373465,1005194799,847297441,406762289,1314163512,1332590856,1866599683,4127851711,750260880,613907577,1450815602,3165620655,3734664991,3650291728,3012275730,3704569646,1427272223,778793252,1343938022,2676280711,2052605720,1946737175,3164576444,3914038668,3967478842,3682934266,1661551462,3294938066,4011595847,840292616,3712170807,616741398,312560963,711312465,1351876610,322626781,1910503582,271666773,2175563734,1594956187,70604529,3617834859,1007753275,1495573769,4069517037,2549218298,2663038764,504708206,2263041392,3941167025,2249088522,1514023603,1998579484,1312622330,694541497,2582060303,2151582166,1382467621,776784248,2618340202,3323268794,2497899128,2784771155,503983604,4076293799,907881277,423175695,432175456,1378068232,4145222326,3954048622,3938656102,3820766613,2793130115,2977904593,26017576,3274890735,3194772133,1700274565,1756076034,4006520079,3677328699,720338349,1533947780,354530856,688349552,3973924725,1637815568,332179504,3949051286,53804574,2852348879,3044236432,1282449977,3583942155,3416972820,4006381244,1617046695,2628476075,3002303598,1686838959,431878346,2686675385,1700445008,1080580658,1009431731,832498133,3223435511,2605976345,2271191193,2516031870,1648197032,4164389018,2548247927,300782431,375919233,238389289,3353747414,2531188641,2019080857,1475708069,455242339,2609103871,448939670,3451063019,1395535956,2413381860,1841049896,1491858159,885456874,4264095073,4001119347,1565136089,3898914787,1108368660,540939232,1173283510,2745871338,3681308437,4207628240,3343053890,4016749493,1699691293,1103962373,3625875870,2256883143,3830138730,1031889488,3479347698,1535977030,4236805024,3251091107,2132092099,1774941330,1199868427,1452454533,157007616,2904115357,342012276,595725824,1480756522,206960106,497939518,591360097,863170706,2375253569,3596610801,1814182875,2094937945,3421402208,1082520231,3463918190,2785509508,435703966,3908032597,1641649973,2842273706,3305899714,1510255612,2148256476,2655287854,3276092548,4258621189,236887753,3681803219,274041037,1734335097,3815195456,3317970021,1899903192,1026095262,4050517792,356393447,2410691914,3873677099,3682840055,3913112168,2491498743,4132185628,2489919796,1091903735,1979897079,3170134830,3567386728,3557303409,857797738,1136121015,1342202287,507115054,2535736646,337727348,3213592640,1301675037,2528481711,1895095763,1721773893,3216771564,62756741,2142006736,835421444,2531993523,1442658625,3659876326,2882144922,676362277,1392781812,170690266,3921047035,1759253602,3611846912,1745797284,664899054,1329594018,3901205900,3045908486,2062866102,2865634940,3543621612,3464012697,1080764994,553557557,3656615353,3996768171,991055499,499776247,1265440854,648242737,3940784050,980351604,3713745714,1749149687,3396870395,4211799374,3640570775,1161844396,3125318951,1431517754,545492359,4268468663,3499529547,1437099964,2702547544,3433638243,2581715763,2787789398,1060185593,1593081372,2418618748,4260947970,69676912,2159744348,86519011,2512459080,3838209314,1220612927,3339683548,133810670,1090789135,1078426020,1569222167,845107691,3583754449,4072456591,1091646820,628848692,1613405280,3757631651,526609435,236106946,48312990,2942717905,3402727701,1797494240,859738849,992217954,4005476642,2243076622,3870952857,3732016268,765654824,3490871365,2511836413,1685915746,3888969200,1414112111,2273134842,3281911079,4080962846,172450625,2569994100,980381355,4109958455,2819808352,2716589560,2568741196,3681446669,3329971472,1835478071,660984891,3704678404,4045999559,3422617507,3040415634,1762651403,1719377915,3470491036,2693910283,3642056355,3138596744,1364962596,2073328063,1983633131,926494387,3423689081,2150032023,4096667949,1749200295,3328846651,309677260,2016342300,1779581495,3079819751,111262694,1274766160,443224088,298511866,1025883608,3806446537,1145181785,168956806,3641502830,3584813610,1689216846,3666258015,3200248200,1692713982,2646376535,4042768518,1618508792,1610833997,3523052358,4130873264,2001055236,3610705100,2202168115,4028541809,2961195399,1006657119,2006996926,3186142756,1430667929,3210227297,1314452623,4074634658,4101304120,2273951170,1399257539,3367210612,3027628629,1190975929,2062231137,2333990788,2221543033,2438960610,1181637006,548689776,2362791313,3372408396,3104550113,3145860560,296247880,1970579870,3078560182,3769228297,1714227617,3291629107,3898220290,166772364,1251581989,493813264,448347421,195405023,2709975567,677966185,3703036547,1463355134,2715995803,1338867538,1343315457,2802222074,2684532164,233230375,2599980071,2000651841,3277868038,1638401717,4028070440,3237316320,6314154,819756386,300326615,590932579,1405279636,3267499572,3150704214,2428286686,3959192993,3461946742,1862657033,1266418056,963775037,2089974820,2263052895,1917689273,448879540,3550394620,3981727096,150775221,3627908307,1303187396,508620638,2975983352,2726630617,1817252668,1876281319,1457606340,908771278,3720792119,3617206836,2455994898,1729034894,1080033504,976866871,3556439503,2881648439,1522871579,1555064734,1336096578,3548522304,2579274686,3574697629,3205460757,3593280638,3338716283,3079412587,564236357,2993598910,1781952180,1464380207,3163844217,3332601554,1699332808,1393555694,1183702653,3581086237,1288719814,691649499,2847557200,2895455976,3193889540,2717570544,1781354906,1676643554,2592534050,3230253752,1126444790,2770207658,2633158820,2210423226,2615765581,2414155088,3127139286,673620729,2805611233,1269405062,4015350505,3341807571,4149409754,1057255273,2012875353,2162469141,2276492801,2601117357,993977747,3918593370,2654263191,753973209,36408145,2530585658,25011837,3520020182,2088578344,530523599,2918365339,1524020338,1518925132,3760827505,3759777254,1202760957,3985898139,3906192525,674977740,4174734889,2031300136,2019492241,3983892565,4153806404,3822280332,352677332,2297720250,60907813,90501309,3286998549,1016092578,2535922412,2839152426,457141659,509813237,4120667899,652014361,1966332200,2975202805,55981186,2327461051,676427537,3255491064,2882294119,3433927263,1307055953,942726286,933058658,2468411793,3933900994,4215176142,1361170020,2001714738,2830558078,3274259782,1222529897,1679025792,2729314320,3714953764,1770335741,151462246,3013232138,1682292957,1483529935,471910574,1539241949,458788160,3436315007,1807016891,3718408830,978976581,1043663428,3165965781,1927990952,4200891579,2372276910,3208408903,3533431907,1412390302,2931980059,4132332400,1947078029,3881505623,4168226417,2941484381,1077988104,1320477388,886195818,18198404,3786409e3,2509781533,112762804,3463356488,1866414978,891333506,18488651,661792760,1628790961,3885187036,3141171499,876946877,2693282273,1372485963,791857591,2686433993,3759982718,3167212022,3472953795,2716379847,445679433,3561995674,3504004811,3574258232,54117162,3331405415,2381918588,3769707343,4154350007,1140177722,4074052095,668550556,3214352940,367459370,261225585,2610173221,4209349473,3468074219,3265815641,314222801,3066103646,3808782860,282218597,3406013506,3773591054,379116347,1285071038,846784868,2669647154,3771962079,3550491691,2305946142,453669953,1268987020,3317592352,3279303384,3744833421,2610507566,3859509063,266596637,3847019092,517658769,3462560207,3443424879,370717030,4247526661,2224018117,4143653529,4112773975,2788324899,2477274417,1456262402,2901442914,1517677493,1846949527,2295493580,3734397586,2176403920,1280348187,1908823572,3871786941,846861322,1172426758,3287448474,3383383037,1655181056,3139813346,901632758,1897031941,2986607138,3066810236,3447102507,1393639104,373351379,950779232,625454576,3124240540,4148612726,2007998917,544563296,2244738638,2330496472,2058025392,1291430526,424198748,50039436,29584100,3605783033,2429876329,2791104160,1057563949,3255363231,3075367218,3463963227,1469046755,985887462],j=[1332899944,1700884034,1701343084,1684370003,1668446532,1869963892],T=(n,r)=>{if(r<=0||r>n.length)throw Error(`Illegal len: ${r}`);let o=0,t,e;const s=[];for(;o<r;){if(t=n[o++]&255,s.push(w[t>>2&63]),t=(t&3)<<4,o>=r){s.push(w[t&63]);break}if(e=n[o++]&255,t|=e>>4&15,s.push(w[t&63]),t=(e&15)<<2,o>=r){s.push(w[t&63]);break}e=n[o++]&255,t|=e>>6&3,s.push(w[t&63]),s.push(w[e&63])}return s.join("")},D=(n,r)=>{if(r<=0)throw Error(`Illegal len: ${r}`);const o=n.length;let t=0,e=0,s,l,i,u,h,p;const a=[];for(;t<o-1&&e<r&&(p=n.charCodeAt(t++),s=p<f.length?f[p]:-1,p=n.charCodeAt(t++),l=p<f.length?f[p]:-1,!(s==-1||l==-1||(h=s<<2>>>0,h|=(l&48)>>4,a.push(String.fromCharCode(h)),++e>=r||t>=o)||(p=n.charCodeAt(t++),i=p<f.length?f[p]:-1,i==-1)||(h=(l&15)<<4>>>0,h|=(i&60)>>2,a.push(String.fromCharCode(h)),++e>=r||t>=o)));)p=n.charCodeAt(t++),u=p<f.length?f[p]:-1,h=(i&3)<<6>>>0,h|=u,a.push(String.fromCharCode(h)),++e;return a.map(c=>c.charCodeAt(0))},F=(n,r)=>{let o=null;for(typeof n=="number"&&(o=n,n=()=>null);o!==null||(o=n())!==null;)o<128?r(o&127):o<2048?(r(o>>6&31|192),r(o&63|128)):o<65536?(r(o>>12&15|224),r(o>>6&63|128),r(o&63|128)):(r(o>>18&7|240),r(o>>12&63|128),r(o>>6&63|128),r(o&63|128)),o=null},L=(n,r)=>{let o,t=null;for(;(o=t!==null?t:n())!==null;){if(o>=55296&&o<=57343&&(t=n())!==null&&t>=56320&&t<=57343){r((o-55296)*1024+t-56320+65536),t=null;continue}r(o)}t!==null&&r(t)},G=(n,r)=>{L(n,function(o){F(o,r)})},A=typeof process=="object"&&process.env.NEXT_RUNTIME==="edge"?setTimeout:typeof setImmediate=="function"?setImmediate:typeof process=="object"&&typeof process.nextTick=="function"?process.nextTick:setTimeout,M=n=>{const r=[];let o=0;return G(()=>o>=n.length?null:n.charCodeAt(o++),t=>{r.push(t)}),r},m=(n,r,o,t)=>{let e,s=n[r],l=n[r+1];return s^=o[0],e=t[s>>>24],e+=t[256|s>>16&255],e^=t[512|s>>8&255],e+=t[768|s&255],l^=e^o[1],e=t[l>>>24],e+=t[256|l>>16&255],e^=t[512|l>>8&255],e+=t[768|l&255],s^=e^o[2],e=t[s>>>24],e+=t[256|s>>16&255],e^=t[512|s>>8&255],e+=t[768|s&255],l^=e^o[3],e=t[l>>>24],e+=t[256|l>>16&255],e^=t[512|l>>8&255],e+=t[768|l&255],s^=e^o[4],e=t[s>>>24],e+=t[256|s>>16&255],e^=t[512|s>>8&255],e+=t[768|s&255],l^=e^o[5],e=t[l>>>24],e+=t[256|l>>16&255],e^=t[512|l>>8&255],e+=t[768|l&255],s^=e^o[6],e=t[s>>>24],e+=t[256|s>>16&255],e^=t[512|s>>8&255],e+=t[768|s&255],l^=e^o[7],e=t[l>>>24],e+=t[256|l>>16&255],e^=t[512|l>>8&255],e+=t[768|l&255],s^=e^o[8],e=t[s>>>24],e+=t[256|s>>16&255],e^=t[512|s>>8&255],e+=t[768|s&255],l^=e^o[9],e=t[l>>>24],e+=t[256|l>>16&255],e^=t[512|l>>8&255],e+=t[768|l&255],s^=e^o[10],e=t[s>>>24],e+=t[256|s>>16&255],e^=t[512|s>>8&255],e+=t[768|s&255],l^=e^o[11],e=t[l>>>24],e+=t[256|l>>16&255],e^=t[512|l>>8&255],e+=t[768|l&255],s^=e^o[12],e=t[s>>>24],e+=t[256|s>>16&255],e^=t[512|s>>8&255],e+=t[768|s&255],l^=e^o[13],e=t[l>>>24],e+=t[256|l>>16&255],e^=t[512|l>>8&255],e+=t[768|l&255],s^=e^o[14],e=t[s>>>24],e+=t[256|s>>16&255],e^=t[512|s>>8&255],e+=t[768|s&255],l^=e^o[15],e=t[l>>>24],e+=t[256|l>>16&255],e^=t[512|l>>8&255],e+=t[768|l&255],s^=e^o[16],n[r]=l^o[B+1],n[r+1]=s,n},E=(n,r)=>{let o=0;for(let t=0;t<4;++t)o=o<<8|n[r]&255,r=(r+1)%n.length;return{key:o,offp:r}},k=(n,r,o)=>{const t=r.length,e=o.length;let s=0,l=[0,0],i;for(let u=0;u<t;u++)i=E(n,s),s=i.offp,r[u]=r[u]^i.key;for(let u=0;u<t;u+=2)l=m(l,0,r,o),r[u]=l[0],r[u+1]=l[1];for(let u=0;u<e;u+=2)l=m(l,0,r,o),o[u]=l[0],o[u+1]=l[1]},X=(n,r,o,t)=>{const e=o.length,s=t.length;let l=0,i=[0,0],u;for(let h=0;h<e;h++)u=E(r,l),l=u.offp,o[h]=o[h]^u.key;l=0;for(let h=0;h<e;h+=2)u=E(n,l),l=u.offp,i[0]^=u.key,u=E(n,l),l=u.offp,i[1]^=u.key,i=m(i,0,o,t),o[h]=i[0],o[h+1]=i[1];for(let h=0;h<s;h+=2)u=E(n,l),l=u.offp,i[0]^=u.key,u=E(n,l),l=u.offp,i[1]^=u.key,i=m(i,0,o,t),t[h]=i[0],t[h+1]=i[1]},U=(n,r,o,t,e)=>{const s=j.slice(),l=s.length;if(o<4||o>31){const c=new Error(`Illegal number of rounds (4-31): ${o}`);if(t===!1)return Promise.reject(c);throw c}if(r.length!==I){const c=new Error(`Illegal salt length: ${r.length} != ${I}`);if(t===!1)return Promise.reject(c);throw c}o=1<<o>>>0;let i,u,h=0,p;Int32Array?(i=new Int32Array(_),u=new Int32Array(P)):(i=_.slice(),u=P.slice()),X(r,n,i,u);const a=()=>{if(e&&e(h/o),h<o){const c=Date.now();for(;h<o&&(h=h+1,k(n,i,u),k(r,i,u),!(Date.now()-c>v)););}else{for(h=0;h<64;h++)for(p=0;p<l>>1;p++)m(s,p<<1,i,u);const c=[];for(h=0;h<l;h++)c.push((s[h]>>24&255)>>>0),c.push((s[h]>>16&255)>>>0),c.push((s[h]>>8&255)>>>0),c.push((s[h]&255)>>>0);return t===!1?Promise.resolve(c):c}if(t===!1)return new Promise(c=>A(()=>{a().then(c)}))};if(t===!1)return a();{let c;for(;;)if(typeof(c=a())<"u")return c||[]}},H=n=>R(n),S=(n=$)=>{if(typeof n!="number")throw Error("Illegal arguments: "+typeof n);n<4?n=4:n>31&&(n=31);const r=[];return r.push("$2a$"),n<10&&r.push("0"),r.push(n.toString()),r.push("$"),r.push(T(H(I),I)),r.join("")},N=(n=$)=>{if(typeof n!="number")throw Error("illegal arguments: "+typeof n);return new Promise((r,o)=>A(()=>{try{r(S(n))}catch(t){o(t)}}))};function C(n,r,o,t){if(typeof n!="string"||typeof r!="string"){const g=new Error("Invalid string / salt: Not a string");if(o===!1)return Promise.reject(g);throw g}let e,s;if(r.charAt(0)!=="$"||r.charAt(1)!=="2"){const g=new Error("Invalid salt version: "+r.substring(0,2));if(o===!1)return Promise.reject(g);throw g}if(r.charAt(2)==="$")e="\0",s=3;else{if(e=r.charAt(2),e!=="a"&&e!=="b"&&e!=="y"||r.charAt(3)!=="$"){const g=Error("Invalid salt revision: 
"+r.substring(2,4));if(o===!1)return Promise.reject(g);throw g}s=4}if(r.charAt(s+2)>"$"){const g=new Error("Missing salt rounds");if(o===!1)return Promise.reject(g);throw g}const l=parseInt(r.substring(s,s+1),10)*10,i=parseInt(r.substring(s+1,s+2),10),u=l+i,h=r.substring(s+3,s+25);n+=e>="a"?"\0":"";const p=M(n),a=D(h,I),c=g=>{const y=[];return y.push("$2"),e>="a"&&y.push(e),y.push("$"),u<10&&y.push("0"),y.push(u.toString()),y.push("$"),y.push(T(a,a.length)),y.push(T(g,j.length*4-1)),y.join("")};return o===!1?U(p,a,u,!1,t).then(g=>c(g)):c(U(p,a,u,!0,t))}const x=(n,r=$)=>{if(typeof r=="number"&&(r=S(r)),typeof n!="string"||typeof r!="string")throw Error("Illegal arguments: "+typeof n+", "+typeof r);return C(n,r,!0)},O=function(n,r,o){return typeof n=="string"&&typeof r=="number"?N(r).then(t=>C(n,t,!1,o)):typeof n=="string"&&typeof r=="string"?C(n,r,!1,o):Promise.reject(new Error(`Illegal arguments: ${typeof n}, ${typeof r}`))},W=(n,r)=>{if(typeof n!="string"||typeof r!="string")throw Error("Illegal arguments: "+typeof n+", "+typeof r);return r.length!==60?!1:x(n,r.substring(0,r.length-31))===r},Y=(n,r,o)=>new Promise((t,e)=>{if(typeof n!="string"||typeof r!="string"){A(()=>e(new Error(`Illegal arguments: ${typeof n}, ${typeof r}`)));return}if(r.length!==60){A(()=>e(!1));return}O(n,r.substring(0,29),o).then(s=>t(s===r)).catch(s=>e(s))}),q=n=>{if(typeof n!="string")throw new Error(`Illegal arguments: 
${typeof n}`);return parseInt(n.split("$")[2],10)},z=n=>{if(typeof n!="string")throw new Error(`Illegal arguments: ${typeof n}`);if(n.length!==60)throw new Error(`Illegal hash length: ${n.length} != 60`);return n.substring(0,29)};export{Y as compare,W as compareSync,N as genSalt,S as genSaltSync,q as getRounds,z as getSalt,O as hash,x as hashSync};
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:77:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1288:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1340:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .mjs] (C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\TemplatingDocuments\node_modules\drizzle-kit\bin.cjs:14724:13)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\TemplatingDocuments\app\db.ts:5:39)

The following is my package.json:
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev --turbo",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.1.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-dismissable-layer": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu": "^2.1.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-focus-scope": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-portal": "^1.1.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-presence": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-primitive": "^2.0.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-progress": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-roving-focus": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-separator": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-tabs": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-tooltip": "^1.1.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.10.5",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.45",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.18",
    "bcrypt-ts": "^5.0.0",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "drizzle-orm": "^0.34.0",
    "framer-motion": "^11.11.1",
    "geist": "^1.2.0",
    "lucide-react": "^0.446.0",
    "next": "^14.0.4",
    "next-auth": "5.0.0-beta.4",
    "pg": "^8.13.0",
    "postgres": "^3.4.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.5.2",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/pg": "^8.11.10",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "drizzle-kit": "^0.25.0",
    "eslint": "8.56.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^14.0.4",
    "postcss": "^8.4.32",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.0",
    "tsx": "^4.19.1",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }
}

The following is my tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext", "es6"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/components/*": ["components/*"],
      "@/pages/*": ["pages/*"],
      "@/app/*": ["app/*"],
      "@/lib/*": ["lib/*"],
      "@/styles/*": ["styles/*"],
      "@/*": ["./*"],
    },
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ]
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}


Below is my drizzle.config.ts
import 'dotenv/config';
import { defineConfig } from 'drizzle-kit';

export default defineConfig({
  out: './drizzle',
  schema: './app/db.ts',
  dialect: 'postgresql',
  dbCredentials: {
    url: process.env.POSTGRES_URL!,
  },
});

I have tried updating my packages, stating in my package.json to use modules however this in turn stops nextJS from working.

Could you please try to use 18+ node version

This is more a suggestion than a solution.

On Node V20.11.0
